# ST2 Default (OSX).sublime-keymap:5:5 Parse Error

Tags: sublimetext2

I get this error when saving Default ST2 keymap file. Is there some way to get a new keymap file that doesnt have this problem?

The error is: `Error trying to parse file: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap:5:5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've added an extra closing bracket to the default.  You should be able to copy in a "pristine" version of the keymap from "Pristine Packages."